# When we implement YOLOv2 in darknet, after every 10 epochs, the image size is changed. How is this happening?

Tags: conv-neural-network, object-detection, yolo

In YOLO v2, after every 10 epochs, the network randomly chooses a size How is this happening in darknet? I'm using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: check your [net] config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the network sized is changed every 10 iterations (not epochs). 
In your `cfg` file, check the `random` flag.

`random = 1` means Yolo changes the network size for every 10 iterations, it is useful to increase precision by training the network on different resolution.

According to Yolo paper :

> However, since our model only uses convolutional and pooling layers it
>   can be resized on the fly. We want YOLOv2 to be robust to running on
>   images of different sizes so we train this into the model. Instead of
>   fixing the input image size we change the network every few
>   iterations. Every 10 batches our network randomly chooses a new image
>   dimension size. Since our model downsamples by a factor of 32, we pull
>   from the following multiples of 32: {320, 352, ..., 608}. Thus the
>   smallest option is 320 × 320 and the largest is 608 × 608. We resize
>   the network to that dimension and continue training.